# How to tackle multiple compound priorities?

Tags: sqlite

In a database model I'm designing, there is a table with a text field holding a formula.
that formula represents a series of compounding operations.

here are few examples of said formula :

- 1i2e3
- (1i2)e(3i4)

1. each letter represent a compound operator (i for intersect, e for except, u for union)
2. each number is a parameter for a pre-formated select query
3. parenthesis, like in regular mathematical formulas indicate order of resolution

A function in the program is in charge of translating that formula into a valid query

**problem** : how would you handle these parenthesis priority in the full query ? as parenthesis surrounding a select query only works in some specific cases, which are not my current one.

let's take the following formula as the argument for the translating function : `(1i2)e(3i4)`

the pre-formated query looks like this :

```
select pic_id
from pictags
where tag_id = ?
```

the question mark gets replaced by a number

here is the call and the text returned

```
>>> translate("(1i2)e(3i4)")
... (
... select pic_id
... from pictags
... where tag_id = 1
...
... intersect
...
... select pic_id
... from pictags
... where tag_id = 2
... )
...
... except
...
... (
... select pic_id
... from pictags
... where tag_id = 3
...
... intersect
...
... select pic_id
... from pictags
... where tag_id = 4
... )
```

as you can see, the parenthesis in the returned text are not valid as a sql query. While I can replace `intersect` with an `AND pic_id IN ([select statement])`, and also replace `except` with an `AND [expr] NOT IN ([select statement])`  it does complexify the function, which is very inelegant.

There surely exist a better way to tackle these priorities, isn't there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SELECT pic_id from`  is added before the `(` of a formula, it will produce a set of result rows that can be UNIONed, INTERSECTed and/or EXCEPTed.